# Problema al asignar value a un datepicker desde un evento click o cualquier función en jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-4

Estoy teniendo problemas para implementar un datepicker. Lo que sucede es que al intentar cambiar su valor desde mis scripts no se ejecuta correctamente.

Si bien es cierto sí cambia el valor en el input, pero no selecciona la fecha en el calendario del picker. Sin embargo si lo cambio en el `ready` lo hace bien.

El código es el siguiente:

```js
(function($) {
  $('#btnNuevo').click( function () {
    $("#fechita").val("12/25/2018");
  });

  $("#fechita").val("08/15/2018");

}(jQuery));
```

```html
<button type="button" class="mb-1 mr-1 btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:-10px;" id="btnNuevo"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Nuevo</button>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-lg-3 control-label text-lg-right pt-2">Default Datepicker</label>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </span>
      <input type="text" data-plugin-datepicker class="form-control" id="fechita">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Ya encontre el problema.. al parecer es algun conflicto con esta libreria: POPPER

```html
            <script src="template/pluggins/jquery/jquery.js"></script> 
            <script src="template/pluggins/popper/umd/popper.min.js"></script>  
            <script src="template/pluggins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
            <script src="template/pluggins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Pero lo quito y ya no me funciona tooltip...

Comment: el datepicker es de jquery-ui?

Comment: ¿Podrías mirar la última edición de mi respuesta? En ella tengo bootstrap 4 funcionando junto con bootstrap-datepicker y popper sin conflicto entre ellos.

Comment: ¿Has probado la respuesta que te propuse? ¿Hay alguna actualización en esta pregunta?

Answer (score 2):

Tras ver tu respuesta es probable que hayas cargado los archivos javascript en el orden incorrecto.

Te recomiendo cargarlos en el siguiente:

- jQuery
- jQuery UI / bootstrap-datepicker
- Popper
- Bootstrap

A continuación tienes dos ejemplos con tu código funcionando tanto con el `datepicker` de `bootstrap-datepicker` como con el de `jQuery UI` y, además, los `tooltip` funcionan correctamente:

## Usando datepicker-bootstrap:

```html
<!-- Hojas de estilos de bootstrap y jquery ui (datepicker) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-I4gvabvvRivuPAYFqevVhZl88+vNf2NksupoBxMQi04=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<!-- Javascripts en orden: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker, popper y bootstrap el último -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-TueWqYu0G+lYIimeIcMI8x1m14QH/DQVt4s9m/uuhPw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="mb-1 mr-1 btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;" id="btnNuevo1" data-toggle="tooltip" title="¡Hola!"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Nuevo 1</button> <button type="button" class="mb-1 mr-1 btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;" id="btnNuevo2"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Nuevo 2</button> 
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label text-lg-right pt-2">Default Datepicker</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </span>
        <input type="text" data-plugin-datepicker class="form-control" id="fechita">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="<em>Tooltip</em> <u>con</u> <b>HTML</b>">Tooltip con HTML</button>
<script>
$(function(){
  /* Importante: iniciamos el funcionamiento de los tooltips */
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  /* Generamos el datepicker antes de trabajar con él */
  $("#fechita").datepicker();
  /* Tu código: */
  (function($) {
    /* Cambio de fecha a través del método "setDate" */
    $('#btnNuevo1').click( function () {
      $("#fechita").datepicker('setDate', new Date("12/25/2018"));
    });
    /* Parámetro de "Date" en formato "YYYY-mm-dd" (recomendado) */
    $('#btnNuevo2').click( function () {
      $("#fechita").datepicker('setDate', new Date("2018-02-01"));
    });
    /* Cambio inicial de fecha */
    $("#fechita").datepicker('setDate', new Date("08/15/2018"));
  }(jQuery));
});
</script>
```

## Usando jQuery UI:

```html
<!-- Hojas de estilos de bootstrap y jquery ui (datepicker) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha256-rByPlHULObEjJ6XQxW/flG2r+22R5dKiAoef+aXWfik=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<!-- Javascripts en orden: jquery, jquery ui, popper y bootstrap el último -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-KM512VNnjElC30ehFwehXjx1YCHPiQkOPmqnrWtpccM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="mb-1 mr-1 btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;" id="btnNuevo1" data-toggle="tooltip" title="¡Hola!"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Nuevo 1</button> <button type="button" class="mb-1 mr-1 btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;" id="btnNuevo2"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Nuevo 2</button> 
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label text-lg-right pt-2">Default Datepicker</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </span>
        <input type="text" data-plugin-datepicker class="form-control" id="fechita">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="<em>Tooltip</em> <u>con</u> <b>HTML</b>">Tooltip con HTML</button>
<script>
$(function(){
  /* Importante: iniciamos el funcionamiento de los tooltips */
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  /* Generamos el datepicker antes de trabajar con él */
  $("#fechita").datepicker();
  /* Tu código: */
  (function($) {
    /* Cambio de fecha a través del método "setDate" */
    $('#btnNuevo1').click( function () {
      $("#fechita").datepicker('setDate', new Date("12/25/2018"));
    });
    /* Parámetro de "Date" en formato "YYYY-mm-dd" (recomendado) */
    $('#btnNuevo2').click( function () {
      $("#fechita").datepicker('setDate', new Date("2018-02-01"));
    });
    /* Cambio inicial de fecha */
    $("#fechita").datepicker('setDate', new Date("08/15/2018"));
  }(jQuery));
});
</script>
```

Aquí puedes ver mi [edición inicial](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/134837/2) .